# Why my java program is failing to load maven plugin?

Tags: java, javafx, maven-plugin

I am working on `JAVAFX application`, and I am using `pom.xml` file, in which I have dependencies, It was working well in my last computer, but when I imported it to another pc than it is giving me an error, that failed to execute `maven plugin`, I have searched over internet, and followed all possible solutions, given out there, but all doesn't worked for me.

**Now I have a question, that why I am getting this error that failed to load maven plugin?**

here is the log trace:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project EmployeeManagement: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

and here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.viremp</groupId>
<artifactId>EmployeeManagement</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>EmployeeManagement</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>com.viremp.employeemanagement.MainApp</mainClass>
</properties>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>VirEmp Technologies International</name>
</organization>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.viremp.employeemanagement.MainApp</mainClass>
                <bundler>EXE</bundler>
                <needShortcut>true</needShortcut>
                <appName>Employee Management System</appName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-native</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-native</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javapackager</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-createjar</argument>
                            <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                            <argument>-appclass</argument>
                            <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                            <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                            <argument>-outdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                            <argument>-outfile</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>                            
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>  
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: run mvn with `-X` to get more informations about the error

Comment: Have you tried Run as > Maven Build with goals clean install?

Comment: no i didn't tried

Comment: @VinkoVorih how to Run as > Maven Build with goals clean install, as I am using netbeans, I am not seeing the option of it

Comment: are you behind a proxy? maybe you are using the wrong settings.xml

Comment: No, I am not behind any proxy.

Comment: First go to the Project Properties > Actions and create your MVN build under Execute goals. You cannot launch project because you have copied it to another computer which does not have installed dependencies in local maven repository. By running clean install, you are invoking maven to start downloading dependencies from repository.

Comment: First try to clean and re install your project with `mvn -X clean install`, if there are any error, back to here and post printstacktrace

Comment: @VinkoVorih Execute goals are disabled

Comment: @TuanBA I have clean installed, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, actually it was throwing an error `failed to execute` because of some other build errors in my code, which were related to `MySQL`, before that I was thinking that let me first resolve this `plugin` error than I will remove that error, but when I haven't got any suitable answer, so than I thought to remove other errors, than I will come back to this and will remove this error, but when I removed my other errors, than the magic happened, and all error goes, that `MySQL` as well as `plugin` errors.

Don't know why, but it did the trick for me.
Don't know why by removing other errors, removed this issue too, what's the relation between all this.

Comment: Probably because the main class now became available. The execution could then safely run the javapackager. Anyway, good you got on.

Answer (score 1):

The exec plugin executes a binary in the path `${java.home}/../bin/javapackager`.

When executing it it returns an errorcode of 1, which is likely to be that it could not find the binary.

Check that you have a valid JAVA_HOME and that javapackager exist.
Perhaps you have a jre on the new machine?

Comment: Good answer, but that's not the issue I was facing.